# How to install Sublime Text plugin for Laravel 4 Artisan?

Tags: laravel, sublimetext3

And so, I'm using `sublime text 3` and I don't know on how to install the plugin [Sublime Text plugin for Laravel 4 Artisan](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Laravel%204%20Artisan). It says in `Installation` tab that `Use Package Controller or create a the directory Laravel 4 Artisan in your Sublime Text Packages directory with source code, and you're ready to go.` So what to do now? I don't get it. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First If you don't have **Package Control** Install it **ctrl+`** and paste this:

For SUBLIME 3

```
import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = 'eb2297e1a458f27d836c04bb0cbaf282' + 'd0e7a3098092775ccb37ca9d6b2e4b7d'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
```

After that you can use Package control with:

⇧ + ⌘ + P and write install and select Package control.
It opens other field to write, in this write Laravel and choose **Laravel 4 Artisan** and wait to finish the installation.

So when you finish the process you can use that plugin to create controllers and models.

Comment: Or go to https://sublime.wbond.net/installation as Package Control installation code can change.